# Which type of connections allow for the server to send data to a client without the client having to ask first?

Tags: android, windows, macos, p2p

I'm sure many of you have come across this realization very early in your programming career.

Suppose there's a connection between a server and a client. The purpose of the client is to act when an alteration has been made to a variable on the server.

***The standard model*** requires the client to repeatedly check for the value of the variable and act when the value has changed.

**Server**

```
string variable = "nothing";
```

**Client**

```
every 1 second {

    string variable = fetchData(Server, "variable");

    if (variable == "something") {

        performAction();
    }
}
```

The problem is hundreds of thousands of cycles are wasted if the variable changes only once per day, and if the client is a mobile device it would drain it's battery and cripple it's performance.

***An alternative way*** would be for the client to listen indefinitely to the server and the server send the variable when it has changed.

**Server**

```
every 1 second {

    if (variable == "something") {

        sendData(Client, variable);

        variable = "nothing";
    }
}
```

**Client**

```
didReceiveData(variable) {

    performAction(variable);
}
```

This way the cycles on the client are reduced to just the n times the variable changes. I'm looking for the highest level of efficiency in client-side (for a single alteration per day a single cycle per day) and the least delay possible (almost instantaneously) between the alteration and the action. Also, in the next step of development I would like to make each client a server and this means **push notifications** can't scale.

**I would assume Peer-2-Peer but can it be made to work for the example above? Are there any other methods or connection types?**

*Excuse my arbitrary programming language.*

Comment: `there's a connection between a server and a client.` Well then the server can send data when the server will.

Comment: The solution is websockets.

Comment: If that's a connection to a MySQL database for example I would have to check for the variable every second on client-side.

Comment: I guess this is what FCM (firebase cloud messaging) is for, instead of pushing messages to device (which is more than tricky especially with multiple clients and there are issues with firewalls etc.) server pushes them to FCM backend instead. Then clients only connect to FCM and take any messages from there, which saves a lot of cycles/battery since it can contain data from multiple services at once. FCM also has elevated privileges so it will work in cases where your app would otherwise be denied.